# jQuery .each() index?

Tags: jquery, indexing, each

I am using

```
$('#list option').each(function(){
//do stuff
});
```

to loop over the options in a list.
I am wondering how I could get the index of the current loop?

as I dont want to have to have var i = 0; 
and inside the loop have i++;

Answer (score 213, accepted):

```
$('#list option').each(function(index){
  //do stuff
  console.log(index);
});
```

logs the index :)

a more detailed example is below.

```js
function run_each() {

  var $results = $(".results");

  $results.empty();

  $results.append("==================== START 1st each ====================");
  console.log("==================== START 1st each ====================");

  $('#my_select option').each(function(index, value) {
    $results.append("<br>");
    // log the index
    $results.append("index: " + index);
    $results.append("<br>");
    console.log("index: " + index);
    // logs the element
    // $results.append(value);  this would actually remove the element
    $results.append("<br>");
    console.log(value);
    // logs element property
    $results.append(value.innerHTML);
    $results.append("<br>");
    console.log(value.innerHTML);
    // logs element property
    $results.append(this.text);
    $results.append("<br>");
    console.log(this.text);
    // jquery
    $results.append($(this).text());
    $results.append("<br>");
    console.log($(this).text());

    // BEGIN just to see what would happen if nesting an .each within an .each
    $('p').each(function(index) {
      $results.append("==================== nested each");
      $results.append("<br>");
      $results.append("nested each index: " + index);
      $results.append("<br>");
      console.log(index);
    });
    // END just to see what would happen if nesting an .each within an .each

  });

  $results.append("<br>");
  $results.append("==================== START 2nd each ====================");
  console.log("");
  console.log("==================== START 2nd each ====================");


  $('ul li').each(function(index, value) {
    $results.append("<br>");
    // log the index
    $results.append("index: " + index);
    $results.append("<br>");
    console.log(index);
    // logs the element
    // $results.append(value); this would actually remove the element
    $results.append("<br>");
    console.log(value);
    // logs element property
    $results.append(value.innerHTML);
    $results.append("<br>");
    console.log(value.innerHTML);
    // logs element property
    $results.append(this.innerHTML);
    $results.append("<br>");
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
    // jquery
    $results.append($(this).text());
    $results.append("<br>");
    console.log($(this).text());
  });

}



$(document).on("click", ".clicker", function() {

  run_each();

});
```

```css
.results {
  background: #000;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  color: lime;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.one,
.two,
.three {
  width: 33.3%;
}

.one {
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

.two {
  background: pink;
}

.three {
  background: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="one">
    <select id="my_select">
      <option>apple</option>
      <option>orange</option>
      <option>pear</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="two">
    <ul id="my_list">
      <li>canada</li>
      <li>america</li>
      <li>france</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="three">
    <p>do</p>
    <p>re</p>
    <p>me</p>
  </div>

</div>

<button class="clicker">run_each()</button>


<div class="results">


</div>
```

Comment: And *not*, for example, `function( value | element, index | key )`, like the equivalent native method `forEach` and every other popular API.

Comment: Often it is better to debug with console.log than alert. Big option list would ruin your window stack with alert.

Comment: `function(index | key , value | element )`  is it valid..?

Answer (score 34):

jQuery takes care of this for you. The first argument to your `.each()` callback function is the index of the current iteration of the loop. The second being the current matched DOM element  So:

```
$('#list option').each(function(index, element){
  alert("Iteration: " + index)
});
```

Answer (score 12):

From the [jQuery.each() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
.each( function(index, Element) )
    function(index, Element)A function to execute for each matched element.
```

So you'll want to use:

```
$('#list option').each(function(i,e){
    //do stuff
});
```

...where index will be the index and element will be the option element in list

Answer (score 6):

surprise to see that no have given this syntax.

`.each` syntax with data or collection

```
jQuery.each(collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement));
```

OR

```
jQuery.each( jQuery('#list option'), function(indexInArray, valueOfElement){
//your code here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#list option').each(function(intIndex){
//do stuff
});
```