# jQuery each index iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a wall of images and underneath some text, with that i would like the image to fade in then its text to fade in.
With this code below, each image fades in then ALL of the text fades in at once.

Q: how can i use index so that the corresponding text will fade in following its image?
I've  [found a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341977/jquery-each-index) but could'nt get this to work.
css:
`.mydiv a, .mydiv p{ display:none;}`

js:

```
$('.mydiv a').each(function(index){
    var c = $(this);
    $(new Image()).load(function(){
            c.fadeIn(500);
            setTimeout(function(){ $('.mydiv p').fadeIn(250); }, 500);// where would i place index
    }).attr('src', c.find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate from the existing `c` variable if there is one mydiv for each p element

```
$(c).closest(".mydiv").find("p").fadeIn(250);
```

or use `.eq()`

```
$(".mydiv p").eq(i).fadeIn(250);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mydiv a').each(function(i, e){
    var c = $(this);
    e.load(function(){
            c.fadeIn(500);
            setTimeout(function(){ $('.mydiv p').fadeIn(250); }, 500);// where would i place index
    }).attr('src', c.find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: anchor tags don't natively trigger a load event, and load event's don't bubble in all browsers.